# Ansible molecule using docker - how to specify memory limit

Tags: docker, ansible, molecule

I have a molecule test which spins up 2 Docker containers, for testing 2 application versions at once.

```
dependency:
  name: galaxy
driver:
  name: docker
lint:
  name: yamllint
platforms:
  - name: molecule1
    hostname: molecule1
    image: "geerlingguy/docker-${MOLECULE_DISTRO:-centos7}-ansible:latest"
    command: ${MOLECULE_DOCKER_COMMAND:-""}
    volumes:
      - /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro
    privileged: true
    pre_build_image: true
  - name: molecule2
    hostname: molecule2
    image: "geerlingguy/docker-${MOLECULE_DISTRO:-centos7}-ansible:latest"
    command: ${MOLECULE_DOCKER_COMMAND:-""}
    volumes:
      - /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro
    privileged: true
    pre_build_image: true
provisioner:
  name: ansible
  inventory:
    host_vars:
      molecule1:
        app_version: "v1"
      molecule2:
        app_version: "v2"
  lint:
    name: ansible-lint
scenario:
  name: default
  converge_sequence:
    - syntax
    - lint
    - create
    - prepare
    - converge
    - idempotence
    - verify
verifier:
  name: goss
  lint:
    name: yamllint
```

I am looking for a way to specify the memory like `-m` or `--memory=` as described [here](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/).

I understand that `molecule` makes use of the `docker_container` ansible module, which support the [memory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/docker_container_module.html#parameter-memory) parameter, but somehow I cannot find a way to make this work in `molecule`.

Any ideas how to accomplish this?

PS: My guess is that this parameter is not yet implemented in molecule, if my assumption is correct that [this](https://github.com/ansible-community/molecule/blob/master/molecule/provisioner/ansible/playbooks/docker/create.yml) is the implementation.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**++Update++**

`--memory` is indeed not yet implemented in molecule docker provisioner.

If anybody is interested, here is the relevant change to the source code:

```
diff --git a/molecule/provisioner/ansible/playbooks/docker/create.yml b/molecule/provisioner/ansible/playbooks/docker/create.yml
index 7a04b851..023a720a 100644
--- a/molecule/provisioner/ansible/playbooks/docker/create.yml
+++ b/molecule/provisioner/ansible/playbooks/docker/create.yml
@@ -121,6 +121,8 @@
         hostname: "{{ item.hostname | default(item.name) }}"
         image: "{{ item.pre_build_image | default(false) | ternary('', 'molecule_local/') }}{{ item.image }}"
         pull: "{{ item.pull | default(omit) }}"
+        kernel_memory: "{{ item.kernel_memory | default(omit) }}"
+        memory: "{{ item.memory | default(omit) }}"
         state: started
         recreate: false
         log_driver: json-file
```

My fork has now been [merged](https://github.com/ansible-community/molecule/commit/01dc3f75356c6401f2fc077847b354c8a298b458) to Molecule.